# How do I block an app from using mobile data even in foreground?

Tags: mobile-data, android-10

I want to block an app from using mobile data even when that app is in foreground. How can I do that? I can find an option to disable mobile data when in background and an option to disable WiFi for an app but I want to disable mobile data for a specific app completely. I am using a Galaxy A71 phone with Android 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Firewall. See [Firewall Tag Wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/firewall/info) for helpful reading.

[Net Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard) is a well acclaimed app that does not need root access. It is an open source app developed by  Marcel and can be downloaded from F-Droid too. It is very effective and has excellent logging features too.

Answer (score 0):

The popular Android distribution LineageOS has a built-in firewall that can block an app from using mobile data and/or WiFi entirely.

https://lineageos.org/